# How to start a exe with parameters in a batch file?

Tags: date, batch-file

I have the problem,that the following code doesn't work.

```
 start "" "datetime.exe" +%s -d "!timestamp!">tmp_datetime.txt
```

in cmd it works well, the variable timestamp is in the right Format.

for cmd I type the following

```
 datetime.exe +%s -d "YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"
```

and back comes the date as unix timestamp.
After running my Batch file with the start command, the *tmp_datetime.txt* is empty

Comment: Double the percent symbol in a batch file. Do you also have delayed expansion enabled?

Comment: You are redirecting the output of `start` to the text file, which is empty; try to add switch `/WAIT`, or remove the `start` command entirely. Anyway, you do not show us the complete code to reproduce your error as we do not know where `%s` comes from...

Comment: `start /B "" cmd /c ^""datetime.exe" +%s -d "!timestamp!" ^>"tmp_datetime.txt" ^"` or perhaps you may need to double the percent symbol ``start /B "" cmd /c ^""datetime.exe" +%%s -d "!timestamp!" ^>"tmp_datetime.txt" ^"``

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use "call" instead of "start". Start will open a new window. I think there goes the problem with.

So try this one:

```
call datetime.exe +%s -d "!timestamp!">tmp_datetime.txt
```

Comment: Should not need to use call or start with an exe file.